AppSource Validation for MS Teams Tab app - use of Fluent components?
I am developing a Tab app for MS Teams that will be listed in the AppSource. In the validation guidelines, it states:
"Tabs must use Teams styled components such as, Teams fonts, type ramps, color palettes, grid system, motion, tone of voice, whenever possible."
Does this mean alerts, snack bars, and iconography must also be from Fluent/Teams app UI components or just those listed areas?
I am unable to find documentation that explicitly states the requirements of components outside of font, type ramps, etc.

You have the flexibility to use your own design components where necessary, as long as they don’t conflict with the overall Teams experience.
You can refer this documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/design/design-teams-app-overview
